# How to convert this hive query to oracle

Tags: oracle, hive, hiveql

I have this hive query:

```
select REGEXP_EXTRACT( lower(column_name) , '.*(build[ \t]*(app)?[ \t]*:[ \t]*)(.*?)([ \t]*;[ \t]*essential[ \t]+reason[ \t]+info[ \t]+compilation.*$|$)', 3) from table
```

How do I convert it to oracle query?

I have tried using `regexp_substr()` but it doesn't work like it needs to. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would help a lot if you could edit your question to add some example data with your expected output so we could see *how* it "doesn't work".

`regexp_substr()` follows the same syntax as `regexp_extract()`, but Oracle (like many vendors) [only supports a specific set of regular expression operators](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/adfns/regexp.html#GUID-C21037C2-0C75-4DFE-BB02-50B331145436).

In your case, the main issue I see is that `\t` isn't interpreted as "tab character" in Oracle. You have several alternatives to match tab characters:

```
with test_data as (select 'build'||chr(9)||':' as s from dual) -- 'build' with a tab character then a ':'
select 
    regexp_substr(s, 'build[ \t]*:') as slash_t, -- doesn't work
    regexp_substr(s, 'build[[:space:]]*:') as posix_cc, -- matches any whitespace characters
    regexp_substr(s, 'build\s*:') as perl_cc, -- same as posix, but perl dialect
    regexp_substr(s, 'build[    ]*:') as literal_tab, -- StackOverflow formatting ruins this, but there was a tab there
    regexp_substr(s, 'build[ '||chr(9)||']*:') as chr_tab -- chr(9) is tab
from test_data;
```

Output:

```
SLASH_T POSIX_CC PERL_CC LITERAL_TAB CHR_TAB
------- -------- ------- ----------- -------
        build  : build : build   :   build :
```

Comment: Hi thanks for answering. I've created a more elaborate question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71488787/how-to-convert-a-hive-query-with-regex-to-oracle