# How to convert a hive query with regex to oracle

Tags: oracle, hive, hiveql

I have this text:

```
Process explanation:The bottle is then melted to form liquid glass;Final activity for manager:Labeling of previous samples
```

I just want to get the part after 'Process explanation' but not include 'final activity...'

So like this:

`The bottle is then melted to form liquid glass.`

This is the current hive query which I want to convert to oracle:

```
SELECT REGEXP_EXTRACT(
               'Process explanation:The bottle is then melted to form liquid glass;Final activity for manager:Labeling of previous samples',
               '.*(process[ \t]*(explanation)?[ \t]*:[ \t]*)(.*?)([ \t]*;[ \t]*final[ \t]+activity[ \t]+for[ \t]+manager.*$|$)',
               3) as extracted
FROM my_table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come up with something like this:

```
with strings as
(SELECT '1Process explanation:The bottle is then melted to form liquid glass;Final activity for manager:Labeling of previous samples' str FROM DUAL
union all
SELECT '2Process explanation:The bottle is then melted to form liquid glass;' str FROM DUAL
union all
SELECT '3Process :The bottle is then melted to form liquid glass' str FROM DUAL
union all
SELECT '4Process explanation: plasma gasification combined with centrifugal activity' str FROM DUAL
union all
SELECT '5Final activity for manager:Labeling of previous samples' str FROM DUAL
)
SELECT str
, REGEXP_SUBSTR(
               str,
           '(.*process[[:blank:]]*(explanation)?[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*)([A-Za-z0-9 ]*)([[:blank:]]*;[[:blank:]]*final[[:blank:]]*activity[[:blank:]]*for[[:blank:]]*manager.*$)?',
           1, 1, 'i',3)
                as extracted
FROM strings
```

Resulting in:

| STR | EXTRACTED |
| --- | --- |
| 1Process explanation:The bottle is then melted to form liquid glass;Final activity for manager:Labeling of previous samples | The bottle is then melted to form liquid glass |
| 2Process explanation:The bottle is then melted to form liquid glass; | The bottle is then melted to form liquid glass |
| 3Process :The bottle is then melted to form liquid glass | The bottle is then melted to form liquid glass |
| 4Process explanation: plasma gasification combined with centrifugal activity | plasma gasification combined with centrifugal activity |
| 5Final activity for manager:Labeling of previous samples | - |

Assuming matching blank group instead of your space and tab list [ \t] is ok.
Edit: Modified the regexp a bit cause with possibility of last group being empty '.*' kept catching entire line.

Comment: If I want to denote that this part may not exist: `Final activity for manager:Labeling of previous samples` how would I do that? I added a * at the end but it's not working: `'(.*process[[:blank:]]*(explanation)?[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*)(.*)(;[[:blank:]]*final[[:blank:]]*activity[[:blank:]]*for[[:blank:]]*manager.*$)*'`

Comment: for other types of strings this part may not exist: `Final activity for manager:Labeling of previous samples` and when I run the query on them it gave null. Example is `Process explanation: plasma gasification combined with centrifugal activity`

Comment: Ok, I've edited the regexp and added your examples to the test dataset.

Comment: also if there was a special character as part of this text: `The bottle is then melted to form liquid glass and up to 50% alcohol is added` how do I include special characters like the percentage sign? I tried this but apparently is wrong lol: `'(.*process[[:blank:]]*(explanation)?[[:blank:]]*:[[:blank:]]*)([A-Za-z0-9-\\/:@\$%\[\]-\`{}~]*)([[:blank:]]*final[[:blank:]]*activity[[:blank:]]*for[[:blank:]]*manager.*$)?'`

Comment: basically `The bottle is then melted to form liquid glass and up to 50% alcohol is added` can contain any character, not just letters and numbers

Answer (score 2):

If those substrings are just like you said, there's a pretty simple option - `substr` + `instr` functions.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'Process explanation:The bottle is then melted to form liquid glass;Final activity for manager:Labeling of previous samples' from dual)
  3  select substr(col, instr(col, 'Process explanation') + length('Process explanation') + 1,
  4                     instr(col, 'Final activity') - instr(col, 'Process explanation') -
  5                       length('Process explanation') - 2
  6               ) result
  7  from test;

RESULT
----------------------------------------------
The bottle is then melted to form liquid glass

SQL>
```

Comment: A big reason to prefer substr+instr to regexp is that they generally perform faster.

Comment: Sometimes the text are not exactly like in the question and I can't guarantee the sequence, the space or tab of the text. The process explanation by come before or after. Will this work in any case?

Comment: It won't, you'd have to switch those *substrings* in INSTR and LENGTH functions.